# Spring No bean defined of type AuthenticationManagerBuilder

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-bean

Lately in my Spring REST API I've encountered a strange exception. Spring tells me that it doesn't find any bean of type `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder`

It doesn't show up everytime and one first fix was to restart IntelliJ IDEA a few minutes and then everything would work fine.

But now, it wouldn't deploy on my remote tomcat server because of that and I can't figure out what to do with it.

The error message :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method authenticationManager in eu.side.thot.Application required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my configuration

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    /**
    * Set AuthenticationManager his UserDetailsService and PasswordEncoder so he can authenticate an user with a given username/password
    * */
    @Autowired
    public void authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception{
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new MD5PasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

And the AuthorizationServerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AuthorizationServerConfig.class);


    private static final int FIVE_HOURS_IN_S = 5*3600;
    private static final int MONTH_IN_S = 31*24*3600;

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer serverSecurityConfigurer){
        serverSecurityConfigurer
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception{
        clients.inMemory().withClient("{client}")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client-credentials", "password", "refresh_token")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_ANDROID_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .resourceIds("oauth2resource")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(FIVE_HOURS_IN_S)
                .secret("{secret}").refreshTokenValiditySeconds(MONTH_IN_S);
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints){
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST)
                .exceptionTranslator(loggingExceptionTranslator());
    }

    @Bean
    public WebResponseExceptionTranslator loggingExceptionTranslator() {
        return new DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator() {
            @Override
            public ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> translate(Exception e) throws Exception {
                // This is the line that prints the stack trace to the log. You can customise this to format the trace etc if you like
                e.printStackTrace();

                // Carry on handling the exception
                ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> responseEntity = super.translate(e);
                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.setAll(responseEntity.getHeaders().toSingleValueMap());
                OAuth2Exception excBody = responseEntity.getBody();
                return new ResponseEntity<>(excBody, headers, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help

UPDATE : My API works, I didn't change anything... If anyone have an idea of where the problem can come from I would love to hear about it to have a better understanding of spring :)

Comment: Seems like missing dependencies. Could you please add your POM or whatever you build

Comment: Sure, here is my build.gradle depedencies
https://pastebin.com/bXWhQGV5

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you missed

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '5.0.3.RELEASE'
```

Also, users should utilize the Global AuthenticationManagerBuilder that is available when using `@EnableWebSecurity` or `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`

Comment: It doesn't work :/ But it made me realize I forgot to post the error message in my original post I'm editing it with it